# Package visibility in Go Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, go

Given the following code file (named server.go) in Go:

```
package glimpse

func SplitHeader() string {
return "hi there"
}
```

and the accompanying test file (server_test.go):

```
package glimpse

import (
"testing"
)

func TestSplitHeader(t *testing.T) {

    answer := SplitHeader()
    if answer == "" {
    t.Error("No return value")
}

}
```

Why is it the following command:
    go test server_test.go

returns

```
# command-line-arguments
./server_test.go:9: undefined: SplitHeader
```

I'm certainly missing something catastrophically obvious.

Answer (score 6):

Use only

```
$ go test
```

from within the package directory to perform testing. If you name specific files as an argument to `go test`, then *only* those file will be considered for the build of the test binary. That explains the 'undefined' error.

As an alternative, use "import path" as an argument to `go test` instead, for example

```
$ go test foo.com/glimpse
```